# Sub-category single post styling?

Tags: conditional-tags

*CLARIFICATION: I'm trying to style the single post view of some categories & sub categories. The suggested solution works, but only on a page of posts from the selected categories.

Eg. If a post has a category 0f 59 (or is a child category of 59) then load a stylesheet.

Here's what I've tried from the Codex-

```
<?php 
// if the category is 59 or a 59 SUBcategory 
if (cat_is_ancestor_of(59, $cat) or in_category(59)): ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/products.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><?php endif; ?>
```

Any ideas why it's not working? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this `if` statement instead:

```
if ( is_category() && ( is_category( 59 ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( 59, get_queried_object_id() ) ) )
```

**Update**: To work for single posts:

```
if ( is_single() && $terms = get_the_category( get_queried_object_id() ) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( $term->term_id == 59 || cat_is_ancestor_of( 59, $term->term_id ) ) : ?>            
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/products.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <?php
            break;
        endif;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks DM, but think I have a syntax prob. Used this:

'code'
<?php if ( is_category() && ( is_category( 59 ) || cat_is_ancestor_of( 59, get_queried_object_id() ) ) ): ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/products.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />?><?php endif; ?>
'/code'

Comment: Anybody have any hints on how to use the  "get_queried_object_id()" bit to add my stylesheet??? Thanks

Comment: @user22537, you have an extra `?>` just before `<?php endif`, otherwise the code looks fine. What is the error?

Comment: Hey s_ha_dum - Thanks for pointing that out. No particular error, just not using the stylesheet I wanted.

Comment: Just figured-out what was going on. The suggested solution DOES work for displaying a page list of sub categories. But what I was trying to achieve though was to apply the alternative style to the SINGLE post view of posts in a sub category. Apologies if the question was confusing - I'll have a look at re-writing if necessary.

Comment: Have updated my answer

Comment: TheDeadMedic - THANK YOU so much for helping me out with this. I literally spent all day looking for answers on this. Cheers!